# Installing cudNN for Ubuntu 18.04 gives "is not a symbolic link" error

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Cuda 10.0 installed in a Tensorflow GPU container in Docker (image tag is `tensorflow/tensorflow1.15.2-gpu-py3`)

```
root@d7284da3dc5c://tmp/external# nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

However, when I run `dpkg -i libcudnn7_7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.0_amd64.deb` on the debian package I found for the most recent 10.0 on the Nvidia developer site for Ubuntu 18.04 I get the following:

```
root@d7284da3dc5c://tmp/external# dpkg -i libcudnn7_7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.0_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 39767 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libcudnn7_7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcudnn7 (7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.0) over (7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.0) ...
Setting up libcudnn7 (7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

Now, I have seen people using tar gzipped versions of the cudNN files but I'm not exactly sure where to get those from the nvidia developer site. I'm not sure if that would help me get the files and copy them over as I have seen in other articles.

However, with my method it doesn't seem like anything installs after I run the `dpkg -i` command but maybe I am just overlooking some things. Any idea what could be a solution to this problem?

Comment: The missing link should be to the Nvidia driver specific version of that library.  At least that's what the Nvidia driver from the standard repos does.  If you installed the Nvidia drivers another way, I suggest you get back to the Ubuntu supplied  Nvidia drivers asap since you will run into problems with every kernel update if you don't.

Comment: @ubfan1 hmm. Interesting. I am running a neural net in a Docker container that is built in a WSL ubuntu layer. The nvidia drivers are on the host machine which is Windows and are used through WSL and then enabled in the docker container. Since there are several layers here, I am curious if I need CudNN on the windows machine or the WSL instance. Any idea?

Comment: No ideas myself, updated the tags for WSL, maybe that'll pick up someone knowledgeable.